# Block Access to Entire Folder and Instead Route to index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to write a .htaccess rewrite rule to redirect all traffic coming to domain.com/system/* back to domain.com.

I've written this so far:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1/ [L]
```

But it's not working as expected, if I go to:

```
domain.com/system/inexistent_file
```

it works. But if I go to:

```
domain.com/system/existing_file.php
```

It will open the specified file instead of showing index.php contents.

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```bsh
Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    # Match against the host, if you wish
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$

    RewriteRule system/(.*) /index.php?/$1 [L,R]
</IfModule>
```

It works for both existent and non-existent files.

The [`[R]` flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) is there because you stated that you want to redirect.

Comment: That did the trick, although, I'm wondering, why the RewriteCond didn't work?

Comment: First, `RewriteRule` itself matches against `%{REQUEST_URI}`, so there's no need for an extra `RewriteCond`. Second, you were mapping everything (`.*`) to index.php file not the segment after `system/`.

Comment: One more note; you probably have something along the lines of `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` in your htaccess file. Right?

Comment: Yes, to use index.php in case the file doesn't exist.

Comment: Right now, I'm so spoiled that I have no idea why I asked that question! Let's see if I get up and running tomorrow.